# Zooming openlayers map to fit in selected features

Tags: openlayers

In my openlayers based application, I need to trigger zoom when user selects features so that all the selected features fit within the map extent.

I make use of this code:

```
map.getView().fit([swLong, swLat, neLong, neLat], map.getSize());
```

(swLong, swLat) is the south-west corner and (neLong, neLat) is the north-east corner of bounding box containing the selected features. These are in degrees.

What I am not sure is whether I need to provide these in pixels or degrees is the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extent should be in view coordinates.  The way you have specified size is correct for OpenLayers 3.  For OpenLayers 4 and 5 the size defaults to map size so you don't need to specify it, but if you do I've included the OL4/5 syntax

```
map.getView().fit(ol.proj.transformExtent([swLong, swLat, neLong, neLat], 'EPSG:4326', map.getView().getProjection()), { size: map.getSize() });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following functions

```
function goToBox(swLong, swLat, neLong, neLat, xview, xmap){
    var xy1 = ol.proj.transform([swLong, swLat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
    var xy2 = ol.proj.transform([neLong, neLat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
    var lonLat = [(xy1[0] + xy2[0]) / 2, (xy1[1] + xy2[1]) / 2];
    xview.setCenter(lonLat);
    var screenSize = xmap.getSize();
    xview.setZoom(zoomByResolution(lonLat[1], Math.max(Math.abs(xy2[0] - xy1[0]) / screenSize[0], Math.abs(xy2[1] - xy1[1]) / screenSize[1])));
}

function zoomByResolution(y, s){
    var circumference = 40075016.686;
    var val = circumference * Math.abs(Math.cos(y * Math.PI/180)) / s;
    return Math.round(Math.log(val)/Math.log(2)) - 8;
}
```

Do not forget transform coordinates to EPSG:3857

Comment: Thanks for input. I assume xview = map.getView(). Right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Answer if this works for you.